# How to insert an jpeg image at the beginning of each bit of text?

Tags: image, html, text, menu

How can I insert a JPEG image at the beginning of each bit of text?

For example a menu wrapper div id with the menu titles inside `<li>` tags?

I want it so that the image shows up at the beginning of each title in the menu.

Answer (score 1):

If that's a list item and you want a custom bullet, then use `list-style-image`:

```
ul li{
    list-style-image:url(http://dummyimage.com/5/F00/fff)
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oGeez/Myg6h/1)

Answer (score 0):

Use a background image on the li:

```
li {
    list-style:none;
    background: red url(//) left center no-repeat;
}
```

Check [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A2Wuu/).